# Como usar a tag <audio> no PhoneGap?

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou tentando reproduzir um arquivo .mp3 da seguinte maneira:

```
<audio src="sound/som.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

Quando abro o arquivo .html no PC o áudio é reproduzido normalmente,mas quando compilo usando phonegap,e abro no android,não acontece nada.
Alguma luz? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você configurou permissão para executar áudio no seu projeto Android?

Comment: Eu faço isso no próprio HTML?

Comment: Não, no seu projeto Android quando importa o projeto phonegap. No arquivo Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Para Android, é preciso setar permissões além de manipular o objeto media com o plugin adequado.

**Permissões no Android**

```
 (in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Objeto Media**

```
// Audio player
//
var meu_objeto_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
```

O 'src' é seu caminho de arquivo.
Os outros parâmetros são *callbacks*.

Depois de instanciar seu objeto Media execute o método play:

```
// Play audio
meu_objeto_media.play();
```

Veja um exemplo [aqui](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html).

Answer (score 1):

A tag `<audio src="sound/som.mp3" autoplay></audio>` so funciona no android 5.x por utilizar o webview como um aplicativo separado, nas versoes anteriores tem que fazer do modo que foi respondido acima